# why server 2012 / 2008 r2 doesn't start threading.task or thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

My Task and ParameterizedThreadStart syntax are:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

1.

```
Action<object> action = (object obj) =>
                        {
                            bool res=calldisconnectedServices(disFilename);
                        };

Task t1 = new Task(action, "start_disconnected");
t1.Start();
```

2.

```
Task<bool> chunkUpdate = new Task<bool>(() => calldisconnectedServices(disFilename));
                chunkUpdate.Start();
```

3.

```
ParameterizedThreadStart ths = new ParameterizedThreadStart(_Service.calldisconnectedServices);
Thread th = new Thread(ths);
th.Start(disFilename);
```

4.

```
TaskScheduler scheduler = TaskScheduler.Default;
var fetchTask = Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(() => calldisconnectedServices(disFilename)).
                            ContinueWith<bool>(
                            x =>
                            {
                                return true;
                            },
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        TaskContinuationOptions.None, scheduler);
```

5.

```
 Parallel.Invoke(() =>
                {
                calldisconnectedServices(disFilename);
                }
                );
```

Unfortunately, the background work doesn't start and I don't know why. Perhaps something related with OS setting because simply

```
calldisconnectedServices(disFilename);
```

calling without any problem.

Please advise why task not working?

Comment: "why i am not knowing?". I think no one else than youself can answer that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"RononDex" after a long time i found the answer myself. :)

I was creating a file inside the function that i was calling inside task. And unfortunately i was using

HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("_some file name");

and now i am using

HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "_some file name";

and now all task is working, smoothly. Because now i am  not getting NULL HttpContext.Current.Server. :)

Answer (score 0):

use [`Task.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var chunkUpdate = Task.Run(() => calldisconnectedServices(disFilename));
```

Its nice and easy.

The OS you are using should be irrelavent, as long as it supports threading.

Comment: @user2927378 I'm genna need more to go on. This works per se.

Comment: genna i appreciate, same code working on local machine but task not start on server 2012 standard.

Comment: me to, but how to grant IIS app-pool to start system.threading task?

Comment: i saw http://brian-federici.com/blog/2013/7/8/ensuring-tasks-complete-in-aspnet-mvc , but sometime its works and sometime it failed